# How can I run a job every 2 minutes through crontab in Linux?

Tags: cron

How can I run a job every 2 minutes through crontab in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

The crontab format is described in section 5 (file formats) of the manual. With most `man` implementations for Linux, you do:

```
man 5 crontab
```

to read it (on some systems, you need `man -s 5 man` instead). `man crontab` would give you the manual of the `crontab` *command* (in section 1 of the manual). See `man man` for more information.

While historically, you'd have needed:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /path/to/script
```

(every 2 minutes starting at 00:00:00)

or

```
1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59 * * * * /path/to/script
```

(every 2 minutes starting at 00:01:00)

With modern cron implementations (including the ones typically found on Linux distributions), you can simplify it to:

```
*/2 * * * *    /path/to/script
1-59/2 * * * * /path/to/script
```

If you want to run it every 2 minutes starting at 00:00:34, you can always write it:

```
*/2 * * * * sleep 34; /path/to/script
```